# Twitter sending continual "suspicious sign in" messages

Tags: twitter

I'm getting a continual stream of messages from Twitter complaining "We noticed a recent login attempt from an unusual device or location."

I have a single account and access Twitter primarily through my iPhone and much less commonly my Mac. I also have a Wordpress blog that can post on my behalf, but I have not done so in some time.

Checking, I see no posts that I didn't make, nor any other "interesting" behavior.

I have received three of these emails today alone. Can anyone offer suggestions on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are "login attempts" then they haven't accessed your account yet. You may want to reset your password or enable Twitter's Login verification if you are concerned that your account may be accessed by someone else.

Login verification sends a code to your phone that is required to actually access the account. Directions can be found here: [Using login verification](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170388)